# Bring to front android during onClick

Tags: android

I implemented the bring to front on android using `ImageView1.bringToFront()`. It works fine in emulator but after deploying in the phone, It brings the image to the front but you need to touch the image again.

This is my code inside the onClick()

```
lastImageSelected.bringToFront();
lastImageSelected.invalidate();
```

I am running the same version on emulator and mobile.

Comment: Show the code inside `bringToFront()`

Comment: bringToFront() is a built in function in android.

Comment: Oh I must be drunk :)

Answer (score 0):

Read the API documentation

> public void bringToFront ()
>
> Change the view's z order in the tree, so it's on
>   top of other sibling views. This ordering change may affect layout, if
>   the parent container uses an order-dependent layout scheme (e.g.,
>   LinearLayout). Prior to KITKAT this method should be followed by calls
>   to requestLayout() and invalidate() on the view's parent to force the
>   parent to redraw with the new child ordering.

You should call the `invalidate()` and `requestLayout()` on parent view of your ImageView.